# in openerp fields.function takes the dictionary as a argument

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

'total_resources': `fields.function(_total_resources, method=True, string='Total Resources', type='char',)` # is my fields.function

```
def _total_resources(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    res = {}
    reqrd_bffr = 0
    trng_bffr = 0
    billable = 0
    list_resources = self.browse(cr,uid,ids[0]).resource_all_id
    print"list_resources",list_resources
    for status_chk in list_resources :
        status_resrc = status_chk.status_id.name
        if status_resrc == 'Required Buffer':
            reqrd_bffr=reqrd_bffr + 1
        elif status_resrc == 'Training Buffer':
            trng_bffr=trng_bffr + 1
        elif status_resrc == 'Billable':
            billable=billable + 1
    total = len(list_resources)
res = {'total_resources' : total,'req_buffr':reqrd_bffr,'trng_buffr': trng_bffr, 'billable' : billable}
    return res
```

when i execute this it gives a error like below

OpenERP Server Error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)    
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1128, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, kwargs)    
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1114, in _call_kw
    records = req.session.model(model).read(*args, **kwargs)    
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)    
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)    
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)
```

---

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/addons/audittrail/audittrail.py", line 532, in execute_cr
    return fct_src(cr, uid, model, method, *args, **kw)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3679, in read
    result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)

  File "/opt/openerp/openerp_7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3803, in _read_flat
    record[f] = res2[record['id']]
KeyError: 61
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a fields.function method, you should return a dictionary with a list of ids as key and a dictionary for values like:

```
  def _total_resources(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    res = {}
    reqrd_bffr = 0
    trng_bffr = 0
    billable = 0
    for id in ids:
        res[id] = {
            'total_resources' : 0,
            'req_buffr':0,
            'trng_buffr': 0,
            'billable' : 0
        }
        list_resources = self.browse(cr,uid,ids[0]).resource_all_id
        print"list_resources",list_resources
        for status_chk in list_resources :
            status_resrc = status_chk.status_id.name
            if status_resrc == 'Required Buffer':
                reqrd_bffr=reqrd_bffr + 1
            elif status_resrc == 'Training Buffer':
                trng_bffr=trng_bffr + 1
            elif status_resrc == 'Billable':
                billable=billable + 1
        total = len(list_resources)
        res[id] = {'total_resources' : total,'req_buffr':reqrd_bffr,'trng_buffr': trng_bffr, 'billable' : billable}
    return res
```

Comment: good work...  but total = len(list_resources) returns [object Object] in the browser as well Billable returns 1  and required buffer returns 2 but total resources must be 3 instead of that it returns [object Object].

Comment: It's normal because list_resources is the value of the field "resource_all_id" of the current object. I think "resource_all_id" is a many2one field that pointed to another object. You should get the value of the field that contains the good value in this object by writing this:
list_resources = self.browse(cr,uid,ids[0]).resource_all_id.the_field_you_need_value

Comment: if i print res[id] it gives the output like {total_resources': 3,'req_buffr':2,'trng_buffr': 0, 'billable' : 1} but in browser it showing [object Object] my xml code looks like <newline/> <separator string="Total Resources" colspan="2"/><newline/><field name="total_resources_a" readonly="1"/><field name="req_buffr" readonly="1"/><field name="trng_buffr" readonly="1"/><field name="billable" readonly="1"/></group>

Comment: and my python file contains  an my python file contains  'total_resources_a' : fields.integer('Total resources'),
        'req_buffr' : fields.integer('Required Buffer'),
        'trng_buffr' : fields.integer('Training Buffer'),
        'billable' : fields.integer('Billable'),
        'total_resources': fields.function(_total_resources, method=True, string='Total Resources', type='char',),
    }

Comment: All fields return as a key of the dict returned by the _total_resources method should be fields.function.

Comment: For example:
'req_buffr': fields.function(_total_resources, method=True, string='Required Buffer', type='integer')

You can also add a multi='total_resource' on each fields.function to have the computation of these fields at only one time instead of launching the computation for each field. See also https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/ar/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type/#functional-fields

Comment: i added fields.function to all fields it is giving  [object Object] to all fields instead of values and one more if i give type='integer' it gave error that expecting float() or somthing like this

Comment: Can you put your code (_columns and the method to compute fields) in a pastebin like http://pastebin.com/ ?